# Use hardware switch to turn off ariplane mode problem in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: wireless, 20.04, network-manager

I have a HP 15-r014TX model numbered laptop. I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 in it alongside windows 8 (actually upgraded fro 18.04). It had a hardware problem causing wifi to not connect but only scan nearby network. So I attached a usb wifi adapter and everything was working till yesterday. Now I have airplane mode turned on and saying it can only be turned of by hardware switch by default that laptop has F12 as the default button to toggle hardware airplane mode. I tried it and popup showed that it has turned it on but it didn't help me to turn that off again. Referring to many forums I tried popular solutions to fix the problem but nothing worked for me. I also checked bios to whether there is an option but found nothing. No I discovered that the problem is only with Ubuntu and in windows every thing works fine.

**output of rfkill list all**

```
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

**Output of lshw**

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: enp8s0
       version: 07
       serial: d0:bf:9c:07:07:fe
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:18 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b5600000-b5600fff memory:b5400000-b5403fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.0
       logical name: wlp10s0f0
       version: 00
       serial: 74:29:af:80:e9:47
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=5.4.0-42-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:b5510000-b551ffff
```

**information of usb wifi card**

```
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter
```

details of wireless pci card

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
09:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev a1)
0a:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
0a:00.1 Bluetooth: Ralink corp. RT3290 Bluetooth
```

I tried switching desktop environments and network managers but nothing worked.

Is there any fix for this problem.

Comment: Please file a bug report, https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+filebug

Comment: I don't think it is a system bug although i reported that as you said. I say that because I even tried reinstalling ubuntu and it didn't do anything.